# Every Submodule of a Free Module is Isomorphic to a Direct Sum of Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra

Suppose that $R$ is a ring with identity and $R^{\oplus n}$ is a free left $R$-module.  Is every submodule of $R^{\oplus n}$ isomorphic to $A_1\oplus \ldots \oplus A_n$ where $A_i$ are left ideals of $R$?

> **Edit:** It appears that this is false, and an example is given in a [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1583985/is-kaplanskys-theorem-for-hereditary-rings-a-characterization). Can anyone explain why the example works?

Comment: Submodules of the form $\{(x,x) \in R^2 \mid x \in R \}$ are not what you're looking for, right?

Comment: @menag That submodule is isomorphic to $R$, which is a left ideal of $R$.  I'm wondering if all submodules of this free module has to be externally isomorphic to some direct sum of left ideals of $R$.  Since that one is isomorphic to $R$, it's an example.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm asking. I'll think about it.

Comment: I had the feeling that vector fields on a sphere give a counter example. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2166903/60589) is the question. Maybe it is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First recall that the ring in the linked answer is $R=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2)$.

An easy calculation shows that $R$ is local, with unique maximal ideal generated by $2$ and $X$, and has a unique simple ideal generated by $2X$.

The module in the linked answer is the submodule of $R^2$ generated by $(2,X)$. Since it is cyclic, it is a quotient of the free module $R$, and so has a unique maximal submodule. Therefore it is indecomposable, and so if it were a direct sum of ideals, it would have to be isomorphic to a single ideal.

But then it would have a unique simple submodule. However, it has two simple submodules, generated by $(2X,0)$ and $(0,2X)$ respectively.

A similar, and arguably clearer, example is given by $R=k[X,Y]/(X^2,Y^2)$ for a field $k$, with the submodule of $R^2$ generated by $(X,Y)$.